# Custom Relative Layout not showing child views

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to create a custom relative layout which contains two imageViews. One image view appears on the whole screen and the other appears in the top left corner of the first image view. Later I use this custom view inside an xml file of an activity. *However the following code doesn't show anything/any views on the display. Just a white view.*. Infact nothing is shown inside the custom relative layout.

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{

    private Context context;
    private int padding = 50;
    private int crossImageSize = 30;


    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        this.context = context;
        init();
    }



    public void init()
    {
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ImageView mainImage = new ImageView(context);
        mainImage.setId(1994);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - padding - crossImageSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - padding - crossImageSize);

        mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mainImage.setLayoutParams(params);

        addView(mainImage);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams crossParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        crossParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, mainImage.getId());
        ImageView crossImage = new ImageView(context);
        crossImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
        crossImage.setLayoutParams(crossParams);

        addView(crossImage);

        Toast.makeText(context, ""+(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - padding - crossImageSize), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TextView tv = new TextView(context);

        tv.setText("hello world");

        addView(tv);
    }
}
```

XML of the activity in which this view is used:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.hello.MyView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"/>

  <ListView android:id="@+id/sample_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just copy-pasted all your code into a project and it's working fine for me. The only thing I changed was the `R.drawable.close` to `R.drawable.ic_launcher` because I didn't have that resource. It's showing a small launcher icon in the right corner and a large launcher icon in the rest of the view. There must be more than this code else we'd probably have the same result...

Comment: @Darwind I am experiencing the same issue. I copied the init code to my project, replacing the drawables with my own. I have the same constructors present aswel. I also have my custom relative layout added to my main activity layout. Yet no textview or imageview is shown, any advice?

Comment: @Darwind if you are intersted, here is my full code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201158/custom-imageview-not-rendering-on-custom-relativelayout